# RTMP vs HLS vs HDS

Tags: android, ios, jwplayer, rtmp, http-streaming

I would like to stream a VOD/Live on following platforms using JW player but not sure which streaming is best suited for each platform

1. Desktop
2. iOS
3. Android

I understand RTMP will not play on mobile devices.

So do I need to go for RTMP for desktop and HLS for mobile or can I use only the HLS streaming for all the 3 platforms?

Or is there any other way to efficiently stream VODs/Live?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply fall back to a vod MP4 file for Android. Here is a set up - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29394/hls-with-mp4-fallback

Answer (score 1):

For live on iOS. HLS is your only option. Because of this I usually like to use HLS everywhere. For Desktop something like JWPlayer premium can play HLS in flash.